# How does depolarization error accumulate?

Tags: qiskit, simulation, depolarizing-channel

Here's my code to define the depolarization error using Qiskit, which included both one and two-qubit errors:

```python
def depo_error(one_qubit_error, two_qubit_error):
    
    noise_model = NoiseModel()

    error_1q = depolarizing_error(one_qubit_error, 1)
    noise_model.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error_1q, ['u1', 'u2', 'u3'])

    error_2q = depolarizing_error(two_qubit_error, 2)
    noise_model.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error_2q, ['cx'])

    return noise_model
```

My question is that after setting up the error rates for one and two-qubit gates, how does the error accumulate? Suppose I have a circuit that looks pretty similar to the Hadamard test:

[image]

And I set `one_qubit_error = two_qubit_error = 0.5`. Is there a way we can estimate how the error accumulates and its effect on the measurement?

Comment: is $U_\psi$ a one-qubit unitary?

Comment: @forky40 I think generally it could be multi-qubit.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find related information in this: [http://theory.caltech.edu/~preskill/ph219/chap3_15.pdf](http://theory.caltech.edu/%7Epreskill/ph219/chap3_15.pdf)

In chapter 3.4.1.  Depolarizing channel.

The depolarizing channel is a model of a decohering qubit that has particularly nice symmetry properties. We can describe it by saying that,
with probability 1 − p the qubit remains intact, while with probability p
an “error” occurs.

You need to learn density matrix representations to walk through the derivation of the error accumulation.